# Identification of sampling frequency

Tags: sampling

I have the following vector:

```
%create vector of sampling
t=0:pi/100:2*pi;
x=sin(t);
```

What is the sampling frequency (of this vector) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A discrete sine wave is defined as
$$\sin (2\pi  f n)$$
Now your index is `n=2*pi*(0:1/200:1)`. This means your sampling frequency is 200Hz.